# How to copy Arraylist of Custom Objects (of Class Place) into Arraylist of Custom Objects (of Class Coupon)

Tags: android, arraylist

i) Class Place (has 3 string variables) ii) Class Coupon (has 4 string variables-3 same as Class Place and one additional String Variable). Now I have ArrayList of object of class Place which need to be copied to ArrayList of object of Class Coupon. SO, basically 3 variables of Arraylist of object Class Coupon will be same as ArrayList of object of Class Place and fourth variables will then be initialized with one another string. How i can achieve that.
And how I can do that vice-versa like copying 3 variables of ArrayList of object of class Coupon into ArrayList of object of Class Place. Please Help.

```
1. Class Place:
public class Place implements Serializable{
    public String mPlace;
    public String mOffer;
    public String mImage;


    public Place(String place, String offer, String image) {
        this.mPlace = place;
        this.mOffer = offer;
        this.mImage = image;
    }
}

2. Class Coupon:
public class Coupon implements Serializable {
    public String mPlace;
    public String mOffer;
    public String mImage;
    public String mItemClicked;

    public Coupon(String place, String offer, String image, String ItemClicked) {
        this.mPlace = place;
        this.mOffer = offer;
        this.mImage = image;
        this.mItemClicked = ItemClicked;
    }


}
3. I have now two variables List<Place>mPlaces and List<Coupon>mCoupons.
If one of variable has complete data then how I can copy it into another.
```

Comment: Instead, you can keep all the variables in `Coupon` class and manipulate.

Comment: Can you explain it more, I am new to programming.Basically I want to pass an Arraylist of Class Place and also Clicked item name to another activity from main activity. So, thought to do this way. Thanks for help.

Comment: All the elements you want in class `Place` is available in class `Coupon`. Then, why do you need class `Place`. If you want two different arraylist. You can use like `Arraylist<Coupon> placesAl  = new ArrayList<>();`  and  `ArrayList<Coupon> couponsAl = new ArrayList<>();` You get my point?

Comment: Based on ArrayList of class Place, I am showing a ListView (basically an Image and two texts). Now there is a series of images (basically categories) there on main activity, once user clicks that I want to pass that ArrayList of class Place and name of that category that has been clicked to another new activity. In new Activity, based on logic, out of all ArrayList, only items related with that particular category will be shown as ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your members of `Place.class` is same in `Coupon.class`, you can remove those 3 members from `Coupon.class` and just extent `Place.class` like this :

```
public class Coupon extends Place implements Serializable {

    public String mItemClicked;

    public Coupon(String place, String offer, String image, String ItemClicked) {
        this.mPlace = place;
        this.mOffer = offer;
        this.mImage = image;
        this.mItemClicked = ItemClicked;
    }
}
```

Then suppose if you have an `ArrayList<Coupon> list = new ArrayList<>();` then you can easily create a list of `Place.class` like :

```
ArrayList<Place> placeList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Coupon coupon : couponList) {
    placeList.add(coupon);
}
```

So your can easily cast coupon class to place class.

**EDIT:** 
You have to create new `Coupon` Object for all `Place` object, the reason is When you create `Coupon` object it have `Place` Instance since it extends `Place` so you can directly cast `Coupon` to `Place`, but you can't cast directly the Vice-Versa. So you need to create new `Coupon` object for each `Place` Object and set the value. Like :

```
ArrayList<Coupon> couponList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Place place : placeList) {
    Coupon coupon = new Coupon(place.mPlace, place.mOffer, place.mImage, null);
    couponList.add(coupon);
}
```

**Note:** If the `ArrayList<Place>` you have is created by casting `Coupon` Object then you can directly cast the `Place` object to `Coupon` object so in this case no need to create new `Coupon` Object for all `Place` object.

Comment: Thanks, i) when I am defining Coupon class same as you suggested, it is showing error-there is no default constructor avaialble in Class Place.ii) Once it has been done then how I can do vice-versa, if i have an ArrayList<Place> mplaces=new ArrayList<>() then copy it ArrayList<Coupon>

Answer (score 0):

You can use theese methods to convert them.

```
public static ArrayList<Coupon> toCoupons(ArrayList<Place> places){
    ArrayList<Coupon> coupons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Place place: places) {
        Coupon coupon = new Coupon;
        coupon.mOffer = place.mOffer;
        ....

        coupons.add(coupon);
    }

    return coupons;
}


public static ArrayList<Places> toPlaces(ArrayList<Coupons> coupons){
    ArrayList<Coupon> places = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Coupon coupon: coupons) {
        Place place = new Place();
        place.mOffer = coupon.mOffer;
        ....

        places.add(place);
    }

    return places;
}
```

I strongly advice to create a base class that has fields which is shared between these classes. And other classes extends it. Then you can use polymorphism. It will make your world to run easier.

Good luck.